# Stimulus controller not registering CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, stimulusjs

I'm using rails, tailwind, and stimulus together. The application also integrates hotwire, but I'm not sure how relevant that is. Most of the code was written by others, so I don't know what someone could have potentially introduced that could cause this result.

I have html similar to this

```
<div data-controller="modal" data-action="click->modal#doStuff" data-modal-target="myModal" class="block bg-red-500">
</div>
```

and a controller

```
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus`;

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['myModal']

  doStuff(){
    console.log(this.myModalTarget.style)
  }
}
```

1. Visually, I can see a red background as expected
2. If I inspect the html, I can see the appropriate classes and css

but when I click on the div, it calls `console.log this.myModalTarget.style` and **everything** in the CSSStyleDeclaration object is empty strings, including `display` and `backgroundColor`

At first, I thought it might be a race condition thing. It doesn't fully make sense, but maybe for some reason the controller is getting the `myModalTarget` before the CSS changes are being applied on the initial page render. But then I modified the controller to this:

```
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus`;

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['myModal']

  doStuff(){
    console.log(this.myModalTarget.style)
    this.myModalTarget.style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

After clicking on the div twice, it correctly applies the 'block' style to the div to the point where if I `console.log(this.myModalTarget.style)` I can see in the CSSStyleDeclaration object that `display: block` as I expected.

However, the value for `backgroundColor` is still showing as `""`

The entire time, I can visually see a red background, but if I `console.log(this.myModalTarget.style.backgroundColor)` the result I get continues to be `""`

I would think that if this were a race condition like the one I described, the backgroundColor details would be updated and show a value of `"red"` *eventually*.

Can anyone see an issue, or at least offer some ideas for what could possibly cause this to happen?

I feel like I've seen this behavior multiple times throughout this application, unfortunately and I haven't been able to figure out for the life of me why the behavior of things are the way they are.

Comment: Just because your Stimulus target indeed has some Tailwind css in attribute `class=" ..."` though it has no attribute `style="..."` so you get no value. If you want to get the actual styling of your element you have to get the computed style : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle instead of the style (this will basically show all CSS, not only the CSS directly applied to the element)

Comment: @Maxence console.log(getComputedStyle(this.myModalTarget).style) does indeed give me the results I'm looking for. I tend to use React more than vanilla JavaScript, so I've personally never seen this used. I assume there's a slight performance hit relative to `style.display` since it's generating a new instance of the CSSStyleDeclaration. Is this unusual for developers to use?

Comment: Well I wouldn't dive too much into performance. Event listeners, mutation observers etc put much more strain on the browser window. I sometimes use getcomputedstyle but I don't see a real use for casual Dom manipulation. Mostly I toggle a class (have I mentionned I have a `hidden` class in most of my repos?) or edit some styling directly in some case. But I know beforehand what I have to do and how my Dom elements look. getcomputedStyle is mostly useful for assessing the size of an element when `offsetHeight` is not good enough .. Don't really know your case ...

Comment: If you want to change a background color in the context of Tailwind, then you have to have a clear view of your element styling state and check for a specific class: `this.myModalTarget.classList.contains("bg-red-500")` and maybe remove it `this.myModalTarget.classList.remove("bg-red-500")` to replace with something else. But actually using BEM CSS and changing the semantic CSS seems more natural. (I dont use Tailwind as my base CSS framework, just for margins, and SASS + BEM for main styling) https://getbem.com/

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle()` and CSS manipulation from JavaScript in general was something we did 10+ years ago when CSS animations where not widely supported and you had to create responsive layouts and try in vain to get it to work in IE. Today its not very relevant - just add classes and let the browser do the work in a way that can be handled by the GPU.

Comment: @Maxence my goal is simply toggling visible and not visible as shown in this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp - but as we've determined, style.display doesn't give me the appropriate values. I could use classes as you've suggested, and that's perfectly valid and seems like it will work - I just think it's a wacky issue and the example in the link chose not to use classes for whatever reason. I didn't expect it to be such an issue.

Comment: You can toggle visibilty through the `hidden` attribute. W3Cschools is a garbage clickbait site. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden

Comment: The example is manipulating style directly on of a specific element. You would better have a class that you would toggle. `.hidden {display: none;}` this way : `this.myModalTarget.classList.toggle("hidden")`. There is probably a similar class with Tailwind that you can toggle. Toggling `block` class would have no effect on visibility. Rather it will affect <span> element which are inline-block by default.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing two very different things.

[Element.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style):

> The style read-only property returns the inline style of an element in the form of a CSSStyleDeclaration object that contains a list of all styles properties for that element with values assigned for the attributes that are defined in the element's **inline style attribute**.

And inherited CSS rules from CSS files or  tags which are available through [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus`;

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['myModal']

  doStuff(){
    console.log(window.getComputedStyle(myModalTarget).display)
    this.myModalTarget.style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```